# FluentValidation calling method with two parameters

Tags: fluentvalidation

I have the following FluentValidation code which I need to change so that the validation calls the IsUniqueCode function and also passes the currentID parameter which is the id of the Language object been validated.

```cs
 public class LanguageValidator : AbstractValidator<Language>
{
    public LanguageValidator()
    {
        RuleFor(x => x.Code).NotEmpty().WithMessage("Language code is required").Length(0, 100);
        RuleFor(x => x.Code).Must(IsUniqueCode).WithMessage("Language code provided already exists");
    }

    private bool IsUniqueCode(string code, int currentID)
    {
        var _db = new MyDbContext();
        var language = _db.Languages.SingleOrDefault(x => x.Code == code);

        if (language== null) return true;

        return (language.LanguageId != currentID);

    }
}
```

This is so that the second time I save the object it doesn't fail the validation that the Language code provided already exists.

The above code doesn't compile because of

```cs
RuleFor(x => x.Code)
    .Must(**IsUniqueCode**)
    .WithMessage("Language code provided already exists");
```

Comment: Found the solution: RuleFor(x => x.Code).Must((x,y) => IsUniqueCode(x)).WithMessage("Language code provided already exists"); and then the function is  private bool IsUniqueCode(Language languageObject).

Comment: You can move your comment contents to answer.

Comment: @panais your comment has been useful to me, I agree that you can move your comment contents to answer